# Как создать геттер в главном классе для другого класса в с++?

Tags: c++, классы

Программу пишу на с++.
У меня есть класс библиотека и в этой библиотека есть поле типом другого класса.  В этом другом классе есть три переменные два интвых числа и третья указатель на динамическую память. В главном классе библиотека я не могу создать геттер на другой класс. Как мне его создать? Проект разбит на файлы.

Заголовок Book.h

```
#include"Date_of.h"
#include"Name_of_the_person.h"
#include"Reader.h"
using namespace std;

class Book
{
    Date_of publishing;
    char *name;
    Name_of_the_person writer;
    char *genre;
    double price;
    int rating;
    int id;
    int at_hands;
    int popularity_of_the_book;
    int time;
    Book *lib;
    int cnt;

public:
    Book();
    ~Book();
    //explicit operator int();
    template<typename T>
    friend T Check(T &n); //вот здесь у меня друг фукция, которую я также подключил до других классав. Чтобы она нормально заработала в сpp файле мне пришлось добавить template<typename T>. 
    void Print_Book(Book &a);
    const char *getName()const;
    Date_of getPublishingDay()const; // здесь я создаю геттер, чтобы получить доступ до дня с другого класса
    Date_of getPublishingMonth()const; // здесь я создаю геттер, чтобы получить доступ до месяца который есть указатель на динамическую память
    Date_of getPublishingyear()const;
    Name_of_the_person getWriter()const;
    char getGenre()const;
    double getPrice()const;
    int getRating()const;
    int getId()const;
    int getAt_hands()const;
    int getPopularity_of_the_book()const;
    int getTime()const;
    /*int setName();
    Date_of setPublishing();
    Name_of_the_person setWriter();
    char setGenre();
    double setPrice();
    int setRating();
    int setId();
    int setAt_hands();
    int setPopularity_of_the_book();
    int setTime();*/


};
```

Сpp Book

```
#include "Book.h"



Book::Book()
{
    name = nullptr;
    genre = nullptr;
    price = 0;
    rating=id=at_hands=popularity_of_the_book=time=0;
    Book *lib = nullptr;
    cnt = 0;

}


Book::~Book()
{
}

//
//Book::operator int()
//{
//  return publishing.getDay();
//}

void Book::Print_Book(Book &a) {
    // not done
}

const char *Book::getName()const {
    if (name != nullptr)
        return name;
}

   Date_of Book::getPublishingDay()const {
      return  getDay(); // здесь не выходит сделать геттер 

}
```

другой класс Date of.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream> // здесь мне пришлось подключить библиотека потому, что не видит в cpp file некоторых функций. Хотя я думал,что подтянет с заголовка библиотеки. 
class Date_of
{
    int day;
    char *month;
    int year;
public:
    Date_of();
    ~Date_of();

    int getDay()const;
    const char *getMonth()const;
    int getYear()const;
    void setDay(int d);
    void setMonth(const char *m);
    void setYear(int y);
};
```

Data_of cpp file

```
#include "Date_of.h"



Date_of::Date_of()
{
    day = 0; 
    month = nullptr;
    year = 0; 
}


Date_of::~Date_of()
{
}


int Date_of::getDay()const {
    if (day)
        return day;
}

const char *Date_of::getMonth()const {
    if (month != nullptr)
        return month;
}

int Date_of::getYear()const {
    if (year)
        return year;
}

void Date_of::setDay(int d) {
    if (d)
        day = d;
}

void Date_of::setMonth(const char *m) {
    if (m)
        month = _strdup(m);
}

void Date_of::setYear(int y) {
    if (y)
        year = y;
}
```

Вся программа переделается со структур и там как вы все знаете точку поставил и можно обращаться до объекта другой структуры. В классах я так понимаю нельзя так делать(или я ошибаюсь?) и мне приходится писать сеттеры и геттеры чтобы для данных можно было обращаться. Другие файлы я не подключал, так как думаю, что для решения поставленных задача будет достаточно показного материала. Всех  с Наступающим Новым Годом и Рождеством Христовым!!!

Comment: Начнем с того, что, например, в классе Book имеете обьект  Date_of publishing, который вполне может остаться неинициализированным, поскольку это не делает конструктор, а в классе  Date_of  нет оператора присваивания или конструктора копирования, чтобы вы могли инициализировать его. Получается, что  вы каждый раз должны прибегнуть к помощи сеттерам и геттерам. По этой и по другим похожим причинам ваши классы не выполняют ничего осмысленного, и они становятся хуже обычных структур данных, к которым можете иметь свободный доступ без каких либо дополнительной писанины сеттеров и геттеров..

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите.  Для решения Вашей задачи есть два варианта (как минимум).
1) В классе `Book` можно написать всего один геттер для даты

```
Date_of getDateOf() const
{
    return publishing;
}
```

А потом где-то в коде будет

```
Book book;
...
int day = book.getDateOf().getDay(); // или другие методы класса Date_of
```

`book.getDateOf()` возвращает обьект класса `Date_of` для которого мы можем вызвать его методы.
2) В классе `Book` Вы можете написать

```
int getPublishingDay() const
{
    return publishing.getDay();
}
const char* getPublishingMonth() const
{
    return publishing.getMonth();
}
int getPublishingyear() const
{
    return publishing.getYear();
}
```

и возвращать день, месяц и год напрямую

```
Book book;
...
int day = book.getPublishingDay();
```

PS. В дополнение скажу, что Вы скорее всего хотели написать `lib = nullptr;` вместо `Book *lib = nullptr;` в конструкторе класса `Book`. Сейчас Вы создаете локальный `lib` в конструкторе и инициализируете его, вместо `lib`, который находится в обьекте.

PPS. И Вас с праздниками!

Comment: я так и пытался сделать раньше по второму варианту но потом столкнулся с одной проблемой, что нету у меня нету подходящего конструктора для переобразования с инт в Date_of. Я не знаю как сделать его так как там есть три поля и они разные по типу. Book*lib  это у меня будет указатель на массив, то есть будет еще массив я до него еще не дошел. Да я там сделал ошибку. вы правильно подметили. Но в конструкторе поставил, чтобы он указывал на nullptr. Первый вариант подходит и писать меньше. Подскажите пожалуйста как сеттеры написать для другого класса.